# I getting this error when running my spark code Error: Could not find or load main class org.example.test

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am running spark code using intellij.

First I create a new project using maven. Initially the structure of src was src\main\java\org.example\Main.java but changed it to  src\main\scala\org.example\test.scala

Now when I run I am getting  Error: Could not find or load main class org.example.test

I have added the dependencies which are needed in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am attaching the snip of file structure .

I can not see out folder .[please find image here for files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKb4S.png)
[please find image here for files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN3ya.png)

Here is the code I am running .

```
package org.example
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
object test {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
  .master("local[1]")
  .appName("SparkByExamples.com")
  .getOrCreate()

val rdd = Seq((1, "ram"), (2, "sita"))
val rddDF = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rdd)
println(rddDF)

}
}
```

I was expecting it would work but it did not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've originally created your Project as a Java Project and later converted it to a Scala Project, which is not the best idea.

I would suggest you get the [official Scala Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1347-scala) and create a new Project as a Scala Project from the very beginning.

Note that IDEA only supports sbt and it's native build system for Scala, not Maven.
So if you specifically want to use Maven, refer to [Scala Documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-with-maven.html).